# Dates in SQLexpress?

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I again have trouble converting a query from access to SQL express:

```
SELECT Sum(T0021_Omzet_prog) AS Expr1
FROM T0021_offertes
WHERE (((T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer])>=#6/1/2013# And (T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer])<#7/1/2013#));
```

Any reason why this should give an error "incorrect syntax near #" ?

My table is not empty:

[image]

1-1-1900 is a place holder, my query is looping through every month so yes, there are dates that fit in there.

Comment: Is there a reason for these downvotes? Or are people just feeling like it, pl0x tell me so I can improve things? Like, I accepted the answer, this is a closed question, why do I still get downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace **#** with **'**

```
SELECT  SUM(T0021_Omzet_prog) AS Expr1
FROM    T0021_offertes
WHERE   ( T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer] >= '2013/06/01'
          AND T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer] < '2013/07/01'
        ) ;
```

But, it will depend on what the `datatype` of the `T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer]`, `T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer]` fields are?

**EDIT**: Query using between

```
SELECT  SUM(T0021_Omzet_prog) AS Expr1
FROM    T0021_offertes
WHERE   T0021_offertes.[T0021_dd_uitvoer] BETWEEN '06/01/2013 00:00:00'
                                          AND     '07/01/2013 00:00:00'
```

**Date Format Above**: dd/mm/yyyy, so this is 6th Jan -> 7th Jan, or do you need 1st June -> 1st July?

Comment: They are date fields? (I think) and if I use quotes it does not give an error, but it also doesn't give answers ;) where as when I use # in the access query builder, I do get results

Comment: Are there any records that match the criteria?

Comment: still no errors and no data :\ I double checked the data type, it's a date/time field ;)

Comment: look at the comments by the other answer, the data is there

Comment: @TheLaurens, take a look at the second query, also make sure the month and day is the correct way round.

Comment: I need the months, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Thank you! I noticed my loop is writing to the wrong fields, but it's definetly getting the data I need! awesome! :D one last question though, is that between inclusive or exclusive? (because I need it to be inclusive)

Comment: @TheLaurens, it's inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following notation, as every other date format may case errors depending on the SQL Server's culture settings (we have experienced even the case where executing queries in the Management Studio interpreted '2013/06/01' as the first of June, while a Stored Procedure on the same server interpreted the same string as sixth of January):

```
WHERE (... >= '20130106 00:00:00' AND ... < '20130107 00:00:00')
```

Please note that SQL Server interprets the time as "midnight" when you don't specify it explicitly, so the above query is equivalent to:

```
WHERE (... >= '20130106' AND ... < '20130107')
```

Actually, this could be converted to

```
WHERE ... BETWEEN '20130106' AND '20130107'
```

Comment: Well, are the records with the respective columns in the given date range?

Comment: Well, the query I posted in my question gives a result when I query the database via access, meaning there should be data. However when I approach SQL express it gives me an error with mine, and not data with everything I try

Comment: My question is: What's in the table in SQL Express? Can you do a `SELECT * FROM T0021_offertes` to make sure that there a) are any records in the table and b) there are records within the given date range?

Comment: I can confirm that there is a butt load of data in the table in SQL express, and that even if I enlarge the data range by a lot, there is still no data, even though there is in the table

Comment: That only partly answers the question: Are the also rows that fall into the desired date range?

Comment: I actually doubt that, because both my and christiandev's answers should work. There must be something else wrong. Try without `SUM` to see the records for the date range.